# How to prevent code executing after a fail inside try/catch in JS

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a JS try/catch structure inside async IIFE (inside another async structure not showed here)

```
await (async function() {
 try {                           
          await myFunc1(),
          await myFunc2(),
          await myFunc3(),
                                   
       } catch (e) {
      logger.info(e)
     }
})();
```

i would like to see script stopped if any of myfuncs fails.
Tried promise all

```
await (async function() {
 try {    
     Promise.all([                       
          await myFunc1(),
          await myFunc2(),
          await myFunc3(),
     ]).then(values => {
      console.log(values);
     });                               
       } catch (e) {
      logger.info(e)
     }
})();
```

But func2 and func3 continued after func1 fails. How should i design code inorder to stop if any of functions fail ?
(my Error comes from an apicall , it gives 400 or 500 error)
myfunctions post some orders to a server, so first one if fails other become obsolete, i should prevent them going if 1st fails

Comment: You can `throw e;` right after you log it (using your first example)

Comment: i tried throw but not worked, can you write whole code ?

Comment: "*i would like to see script stopped if any of myfuncs fails*" - that is exactly what your first snippet already **does**. If it doesn't stop, then that's a problem with your `func1()` - it doesn't return a promise that rejects on failure. Please add its code to your post.

Comment: Do not use an immediately invoked `async` function in a context where you can `await`. Just write the `try`/`catch` directly. Also I'd recommend to use semicolons instead of commas for line separators (it doesn't change anything here, but still).

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a `throw e;` after logging the error:

```js
// For the demo...
const logger  = { info: console.log },
      myFunc1 = () => Promise.resolve(),
      myFunc2 = () => Promise.reject("Err in myFunc2"), // rejects
      myFunc3 = () => Promise.resolve();

async function runAll() {
  try {
    await myFunc1();
    await myFunc2(); // Rejects
    await myFunc3(); // Not executed
  } catch (e) {
    logger.info(e);
    throw e;
  }
}

(async () => {
  await runAll();
  logger.info('This will not be logged'); // Won't be logged
})();
```

Comment: i tried adding throw inside catch but that doesnt changes anytinhg :(

Comment: I used your code example (almost). If you want more help, you will need to add code that reproduces the issue in your question

Answer (score 1):

Seems like main problem is inside myFunc() definition. I put a throw e; inside catch block on that functions scope so it solved.